# vscode won't build

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex

I installed texlive correctly and installed the tex workshop in vscode. But when I click "build", the sofware is not responding, without any feedback.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `document` environment and a package which defines the `align*` environment, e.g. `amsmath`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
lll
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

That being said, you seem to still be at the start of potentially great friendship with LaTeX. To make things easier, I highly suggest a dedicated latex editor like texstudio. This will provide better support to avoid mistakes like this. For example for running your document, it would have given you the following summary of errors:

[image]

I also don't know where your `Tutorial_4.tex` comes from, but I would recommend https://www.learnlatex.org/ if you want to learn latex.